# How to generalise the python used for Docker images?

Tags: python, docker

Sorry if this is a bad question, I am still a beginner at Docker so I seek your understanding on this.

I am attempting to dockerize an application. In the application, there is a json config file which states the python's file path. It is used as different machines have different paths to python.

For example,

`{
"python_file_path":"/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/python",
"other_config":"exampleconfig"
}`.

This config file was originally in the project folder that I was trying to dockerize.

However aftering dockerizing the app and trying to run my image on another machine, the following error shows up:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/python': '/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/python'`

Hence, I was wondering how does Docker package the python required exactly when building an image? Also, how can I change the json file such that it generalizes across all machines?

Here is my dockerfile. My run command was `docker run -p 4000:80 nlpengine`

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /transfer_learning

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /transfer_learning

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install gcc mono-mcs
RUN apt-get -y install unixodbc unixodbc-dev
RUN apt-get -y install --reinstall build-essential
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m spacy download en

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "nlp_engine_daemon.py"]
```

Comment: Can you provide your `dockerfile` and `docker run` command. Also whether this file `/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/python` is supposed to be inside container or on the host itself.

Comment: @mchawre Ok, I have edited my original question with the items requested. Please take a look

Comment: Please provide (relevant parts of) the JSON configuration file, and some background why Python needs to be configured there. You'd typically run Python scripts just with the command `python`. That way, you can activate a conda environment or just put Python into the search PATH without having to change a configuration setting.

Comment: Where the `python` executable is depends on the image you choose. Docker doesn't do that, it depends on the install location of Python within the image used. It's probably gonna be `/usr/local/bin/python` in most images. Really though, you should avoid hardcoding any paths anywhere. Why is it necessary for that path to be hardcoded in the JSON file?

Comment: BTW, you can figure out where Python is with something like `docker run --rm python:3.7-slim which python`.

Comment: @deceze from what I see in this code that was handed down to me, it is used in `subprocess.Popen()` to execute another script. Is there another way to do this? Also, when running that command you suggested, I had `/usr/local/bin/python` as well.

Comment: Within a Python script, `sys.executable` points to the current Python interpreter.

Comment: can you a share a link of github of such project